# UFT One Error: Index was out of range must be non negative and less than the size of the string

Tags: authentication, automation, hp-uft

Getting this error while trying to log in to an application on a desktop. It says to enter the credentials even when the credentials entered are perfectly fine.
Below is the UFT VB script I am using:

```
SystemUtil.Run "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\****\Applications\*********.url"
SwfWindow("Authentication").SwfEdit("textBoxUserName").Set "*************"
SwfWindow("Authentication").SwfEdit("textBoxUserName").Type  micTab
SwfWindow("Authentication").SwfEdit("textBoxPassword").SetSecure "637dbb6663***************************41ffe0b8ef34"
SwfWindow("Authentication").SwfEdit("textBoxPassword").Type  micReturn
```

Tried: using different script, nothing worked.
Expectation: The app to get automated and to logged in easily

Comment: Which line raises the error? Is the error in UFT or the AUT? (Application under test)